# General Triangle Inequality of a function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $\phi : [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ have the following properties: Assume

$$\phi(0)=0, \phi(s)<\phi(s+t)\leq \phi(s)+\phi(t)$$
with $ s\geq0,t>0$.

Prove that if $d(x,y)$ is symmetric and satisfies the triangle inequality, so does
$$\delta(x,y) = \phi(d(x,y))$$

I have been reasoning with this for a while, and I feel like it must be a very simple, short solution, but I don't know how to complete it.

I want to show that $\delta(x,y) \leq \delta(x,z) + \delta(y,z)$, or namely that $\phi(d(x,y)) \leq \phi(d(x,z)) + \phi(d(y,z))$.

I know that I have to utilize the triangle inequality of $d(x,y)$ somehow on the left-hand side, working with $\phi(d(x,y))$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $\phi(s)<\phi(s+t)$. Let $s'=d(x,y)\geq 0$ and let $t'=d(x,z)+d(y,z)-d(x,y)\geq 0$. We have :

$$\phi(d(x,y))=\phi(s')<\phi(s'+t')=\phi(d(x,z)+d(y,z))$$

Now, since $\phi(s+t)\leq \phi(s)+\phi(t)$, we directly have :

$$\phi(d(x,z)+d(y,z))\leq \phi(d(x,z))+\phi(d(y,z))$$

Comment: This makes sense. I just got hung up on that fact that t=d(x,z)+d(yz)-d(x,y) >=0, instead of greater than, which doesn't match the definition of our function. However, I guess that the case of equality is trivial anyway, in which case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Indeed, $t'=d(x,z)+d(y,z)-d(x,y)= 0$ only if $z$ lies exactly between $x$ and $y$. So you could make the argument with a $z$ that is not between those two and you'd get $t'>0$. Then proving the proposition with $t'=0$ would be even easier.